# geolocalization algo transform bidimention to one

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I have a feeling of a solution that I can't express:

As we know, geopoints are limited in the lat and lng numbers (let's say limited to 50). So if we consider a square with a length of `3` and height of `3`, we can express all combinations of points in a unique number between `0` and `9` (`3x3`) right?

For example for the coordinates of `x=3`, `y=2` we could say that `3x2 = 6` expresses two points (`3,2`) and (`2,3`). So if we add a dimension to differentiate the two points, we could express the two dimensional space in a single number. Let's say that if y-x>0 we add 10 so we can differentiate `(3,2) = 6` and `(2,3) = 16` (just to keep simple: we could have added `9` to gain space in our digit base, but it's complex enough so let's solve aside problems simply)

Now, that solution could be good, but I still have a problem: I want the 1-D numbers to be near to each others if the points are near to each other. The solution which adds `10 if y > x` works fine until the `45°` points but after that it explodes to numbers that are very far even if two points are just next to each other (just each is on a side of the median).

So how could you imagine a solution that uses the same range (`9x2`) but where points that are near to each other have a small 1-D distance too?

Thought about using odd and even digit after let's say the 3rd digit ex: `2.5481` and `2.5480` to differentiate points against the `y<x` criterion but I'm still not convinced. Comments are welcome

PS: Keep in mind that I'm limiting the range of possibilities for example you would say: "yes but `6` can express `2x3, 3x2 and 2.7x2.222`" so to answer to that let's only fix the number of digits. if we want one digit after `0`, we multiply all by `10` and we're done.

It's easy to imagine we can give a unique number to each cell of a chess game: we then transformed a 2-D image to a 1-D representation. The issue is to make 2-D distances reflected in the 1-D number

Comment: So you basically want to find continuous map between 2d cartesian space and 1d cartesian space?

Comment: You can try to use Cantor pairing function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function

Comment: Hi Yevgeniy, thanks a lot for your link, I'm happy some mathematicians already targeted the issue. My problem is a little more complex in the fact that I want to predict the distance throught the single value:

I mean I want the world map in a 1D big number, but I also want to predict which points are at a distance less than D to any point N (and for some predefined D if that can make it easier): I can even have a unique D and replicate the data for each distance. But I must be able to find N-D < n < N+D.
I'll look further to the Cantor function and get back to you :)
Definitely a good start

Comment: Looking to your solution, it's really great that we can find back the original values from the result. it seams also that since we have an additional k2 in the function, it is more sensible to distances on the y axis than on the x axis.

Let's formulate the problem in a different way: the distance to the root point can be expressed as sqrt( (x-0)²+(y-0)² )

Applying the Cantor function on the point (x,y) and all the points of the cercle around it (ray D). Maybe I could express it as z-d'<z<z+d''

very very thanks :-)
I Googled : "pairing function" that predicts distance. funny results :)

Comment: I mean
z-d'< z <z+d'

where d' = D²+3D (or approximately that I would say). 

We still have the distance on pure Y axis equal to D²+4D but I could afford that difference maybe...

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a space-filling curve, such as a Hilbert Curve. Points that are nearby each other on a grid tend to be nearby each other in their position along the Hilbert curve. Of course, this is only "on average"; any space-filling curve is going to have certain pairs of points that are nearby in space but far away on the curve.

Comment: But how do you think I should write it? I mean do I have to compute a curve for each geo-point request? The thing is that I have one point, and I need to find the points that are near to it. So if my map is full of points, I don't need all the points, but only the ones that are near my request. This may lead to computing a curve per request no? (sorry I'm a little lost :-)

Comment: I marked your answer as the right one since the Hilbert curve seams to address my issue. I'll have to read about it (for now, I solved my problem differently: by putting points in a tree structure (which solves my problem since I'm handling geographic points and administrative limits can do the trick). Anyway I'll read about the Hilber curve, sounds great
p.s: sorry for the previous comment, I was too deep in my problem to  understand things abstractly :)

Answer (score 1):

A space-filling-curve reduce the dimension for example from 2d to 1d and can help sometimes. It also named monster curve because the curve completely fills the plane. You can compute it with recursion and L-systems. There is also non-recursive approach. You can download my php class hilbert-curve @ phpclasses.org. It uses a table based approach. You can find details also in the hackers delight book and Nick's spatial index quadtree blog.

Answer (score -1):

> Thought about using odd and even digit

You're actually close. While others suggested a **Hilbert curve**, search for Morton or [Z-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve), it's another space-filling curve. However, the forward and inverse conversions of 2D to 1D coordinates (once quantized) is really straightforward, simply interleave and de-interleave the bits of the point/curve coordinates:

```
def unpack_bits(val):
    val = ((val << 8) | val) & 0x00FF00FF
    val = ((val << 4) | val) & 0x0F0F0F0F
    val = ((val << 2) | val) & 0x33333333
    val = ((val << 1) | val) & 0x55555555
    return val

def pack_bits(val):
    val &= 0x55555555
    val = ((val >> 1) | val) & 0x33333333
    val = ((val >> 2) | val) & 0x0F0F0F0F
    val = ((val >> 4) | val) & 0x00FF00FF
    val = ((val >> 8) | val) & 0x0000FFFF
    return val

def map(x, y):
    return unpack_bits(x) | (unpack_bits(y) << 1)

def unmap(s):
    return (pack_bits(s), pack_bits(s >> 1))
```

Comment: A hilbert-curve isn't easy at all. It's not trivial transformation.

Comment: @Phpdna First, I am referring to Z-order space-filling curves and not Hilbert ones. Second, the actual forward and reverse conversions for Z-order curves can be described in a few words "(de)interleave the bits of the coordinates" and implemented in only a little more than 10 lines of code, so in this sense it is simple.

Answer (score -1):

What about using the sign instead of the +10 criterion? Let's say the z > 0 when x > y and z < 0 when x < y. To evaluate the distance between two points, just compare their absolute values ;)